# Registry Editor - .bat file What to type in the file to get rid of the pop-up screen?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

In my code (below) I added a file to the Registry Editor so my VHD is added at the start. When I boot up it shows a pop-up screen stating that the VHD was mounted. I'd like to have the mounting happen in the background without a pop-up screen showing. Is this possible to do in the .bat file or is it something I'd have to edit in the registry editor?

```
@echo off
SET TEMPFILE="%TEMP%%RANDOM%.TXT"
echo SELECT VDISK FILE=F:\mount.vhd>%TEMPFILE%
echo ATTACH VDISK>>%TEMPFILE%
DISKPART /s %TEMPFILE%
del %TEMPFILE%
```

Comment: Exactly what pop-up are you seeing?  What version of Windows are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out to attach vhd without UAC Prompt.

First Create a folder named **C:\Scripts**
Under Scripts Folder Create to Files.

*C:\Scripts\myvhd.txt*

*C:\Scripts\StartMyVHD.bat*

## **Using DiskPart to Attach VHD Silently**

Create a text file **"myvhd.txt"**

Input VHD Info you want to attach with following two lines:

```
select vdisk file="<Full Path to VHD>"
attach vdisk
```

For example:

```
select vdisk file="c:\Test.vhd"
attach vdisk
```

Save the file and close.

create another file named as **StartMyVHD.bat**

```
@echo off
diskpart /s c:\Scripts\myvhd.txt
exit
```

**Now bypass the UAC Prompt**

**Open Task Scheduler -:**

1. Create a New Task - Name it Something like - **StartVHDTask**
2. Select the Actions Tab and click New
3. Browse/Select the location of c:\Scripts\StartMyVHD.bat
4. Now goto General Tab and **select/tick** the ***Run with Highest privileges*** option

*(Optional If Required)*

## **Commandline to add to Task Scheduler**

```
schtasks.exe /create /tn "StartVHDTask" /sc ONSTART /TR "C:\Scripts\StartMyVHD.bat" /ru SYSTEM /RL HIGHEST
```